# Hide time in Android notification without using custom layout

Tags: android, notifications

In the bottom right corner of a standard Android notification is time (eg 12:00). Can I hide it without using custom notification layout?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From API Level 17 onwards, you can use setShowWhen(false)

> public Notification.Builder setShowWhen (boolean show)
>
> Added in API level 17 Control whether the timestamp set with setWhen
>   is shown in the content view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setShowWhen(boolean)

Comment: Looks good, but it doesn't actually work for me in Android 4.3 (API level 18).

Comment: @Sam it should work on API level 18. Feel free to share more about your code and the error you're getting?

Comment: Oh; I was actually using `NotificationCompat.Builder` rather than `Notification.Builder`. Looks like it works fine when I use `Notification.Builder`. Sorry for the wrong feedback. (If you edit your answer, I can remove the downvote.)

Comment: Marking as accepted, this is the best solution now.

Answer (score 45):

For API level 17 and onward, the above accepted answer by Erwan is correct.

### For historical purposes, the answer below remains

It is possible to do that.

Try setting when to 0.
For the few notifications that don't do that, it looks like thats what they do.

Here's the general [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html).

Here's a link to the [ADB notification](http://pdn-slatedroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r43/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java) and search for  private void updateAdbNotification()...

Comment: I have same problem ? How can is solve it ? If i set notification.when = 0 I have time.

Comment: `builder.setWhen(0)` removed the time.

Comment: the problem then is it's always in the bottom of the drawer, not arranged chronologically. no other good option besides custom layout or API 17+?

Comment: @SteveM, what about increasing the notification priority?

Answer (score 1):

For API level 17 and onward, 
mBuilder.setShowWhen(boolen);

1.Use Hide Notification Time

mBuilder.setShowWhen(false);

2.Use Show Notification Time

mBuilder.setShowWhen(true);