# How to hide default notification's time?

Tags: android, notifications

I have been searching method to hide time in notificatin, but I couldn't do.

I have found

setShowWhen(false)

But it is not shown in my ADT.
It exists in reference.
I don't know why I cant use it. 
Customizing layout is not good to see.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `setShowWhen` is API level 17 - are you using a previous version?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757997/hide-time-in-android-notification-without-using-custom-layout

Comment: I missed that ! Thanks @MohammadKhatri