# Notification android show date

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-notifications

On the right side of notification android is showing time. It is possible to show both, date and time as I didn't found any notification api to set the date. Or it is android behaviour to show only time?

[image]

Comment: not sure may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757997/hide-time-in-android-notification-without-using-custom-layout?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use `RemoteViews` for customize a notification layout.
With RemoteViews you can easily control interface and action with notification.
Refer more than here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html.

Comment: Thats one nice solutions. I never know we can use remote view with custom layout.

Comment: Remember have 2 layout notification. Small layout and large layout.